# Content Migration to Sitecore from other resources like SQL

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a site developed in core .Net with SQL server Database. Now i want to redesign my site using Sitecore. How the data/content can be migrated from SQL database to Sitecore CMS?

Comment: There are a lot good options for importing data in Sitecore. like Sitecore powershell, and import tools from the marketplace, or custom build. this is more a question for community.sitecore.net

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has released the Data Exchange Framework. This tool allows you to sync content from third party application. Example:

1. Read contacts from a CRM and create contacts in xDB
2. Update a contact in CRM using information from a contact in xDB

3.Create items in Sitecore that represent products in a catalog

So, you can easily use this tool to import your data from sql to sitecore. You only have to develop the different logic that requires to translate the data from the SQL to the template of your new instance.

Here is the link where you can have the 2 released version:

V1.0: https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/1x/Data_Exchange_Framework_10.aspx

V1.1: https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/1x/Data_Exchange_Framework_11.aspx

From the links, Sitecore has already specified the released note, required documentation about the API and so on.